# Is ground model $\Sigma_n$ truth $\Sigma_n$-definable in every forcing extension?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

It is well-known (and quite useful) that for any formula $\phi$, forcing poset $\mathbb{P}$, $p\in\mathbb{P}$, and $\mathbb{P}$-name $\dot{a}$, $p\Vdash_{\mathbb{P}}\phi(\dot{a})$ is definable as a relation between $p$, $\mathbb{P}$, and $\dot{a}$ with the same complexity as $\phi$ itself (minimum $\Sigma_1$ or $\Pi_1$). Thus a model of set theory not only has a degree of access to the truths of its own forcing extensions, but this access does not come at the cost of increased formula complexity. Does it have similarly "free" access to the truths of its forcing grounds?

The obvious way to assert that a formula holds in some forcing ground is to restrict all the quantifiers of the formula, i.e. assert that the bound variables must satisfy the formula defining the ground. The uniform definition of ground models due to Joel Hamkins (and to my knowledge most clearly spelled out immediately after Lemma 9 of Fuchs, Hamkins, and Reitz's ["Set-Theoretic Geology"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4776)) is $\Sigma_2$, since it expresses that an object $x$ is in a particular ground by saying that there exist a beth fixed point $\theta$ of sufficiently large cofinality and an $M\subseteq V_\theta$ such that $x\in M$ and certain properties which only involve quantifying over $V_\theta$, $M$, and a parameter $r$ hold. Therefore if we restrict the quantifiers of a $\Sigma_n$ formula to a ground model, we will get a $\Sigma_{n+1}$ formula (with $r$ as an added parameter), while $\Pi_n$ formulas become $\Pi_{n+1}$.

Is there some alternative method of defining ground model truth which does not produce this increase in formula complexity? Alternatively, is there some clear obstacle to such a definition?

I believe this is equivalent to the question of whether small forcing can ever increase the degree of $\Sigma_n$-correctness of a larger cardinal, if anyone knows anything about that.

Comment: Nice question! I interpret the question as asking, if the universe is a forcing extension of a ground model $V=W[G]$, then is the $\Sigma_n$-truth predicate for $W$ definable in $V$ with complexity $\Sigma_n$? (So I might suggest changing the title to refer to "every forcing extension" rather than "a forcing extension", which suggests you might make it definable by furhter forcing. And indeed, one can make the ground model $\Sigma_n$ truth of $W$ even $\Sigma_2$ definable in a further class forcing extension $V[H]$.)

Comment: Your final remark about whether small forcing can ever increase the degree of correctness seems very relevant and is intriguing. If it is not answered here, I would find it worthwhile to have an MO question just about that, apart from set-theoretic geology.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I changed the title.

Comment: Are you allowing arbitrary parameters in definitions? If so, doesn't the usual $\Sigma_2$-in-a-parameter definition of a ground give such a reduction of truth (that is, without increase in complexity) in case $n\geq 2$? So then the only remaining case is $n=1$.

Comment: @FarmerS I see how to express the higher quantifiers by relativizing them to the $\Sigma_2$ definable class, but how does one handle the very last quantifier? It seems the natural way to do it will increase complexity by $1$ for the expression over all. Or perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: For example, if $W$ is the $\Sigma_2$ definable ground model, then $(\exists x\forall y \,\varphi(x,y))^W$, for $\varphi\in\Delta_0$ is $\exists x [W(x)\wedge \forall y (W(y)\to \varphi(x,y))]$, which seems to have complexity $\Sigma_3$, not $\Sigma_2$.

Comment: It seems the answer is simply false for $n=1$, since if we could define the $\Sigma_1$ satisfaction class for $W$ in a $\Sigma_1$ manner, then we could define $W$ itself in a $\Sigma_1$ manner, since it is at bottom the projection of the satisfaction class onto the second coordinate. But this doesn't seem to answer for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Fix a ground $W$ of $V=W[G]$ and a sufficient parameter $p$. The relation $w=V_\alpha^{W}$ is then $\Sigma_2^V(\{p\})$, and so if $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_2$ then the relation "$x\in W$ and $W\models\varphi(x)$" is also $\Sigma_2^{V}(\{p\})$. Now just propagate up through higher $\Sigma_n$.

Comment: Do you know an example where a ground is not $\Sigma_1$ in parameters?

Comment: Ah, I see. That relation $w=V_\alpha^W$ is actually $\Delta_2(p)$, right?, because we can observe whether it is true or not in any sufficient $V_\theta$ above $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, $\Delta_2$ in $p$.

Comment: OK, once we get the non-$\Sigma_1$-definable ground (which seems very likely), then this completely answers the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that arbitrary parameters are allowed in making definitions (since parameters are used in the usual definitions of grounds).
Then for $n\geq 2$, there is a positive answer. Let $V\models$ ZFC and $\mathbb{P}\in V$ be a forcing and $G$ be $(V,\mathbb{P})$-generic.
Then there is a parameter $p\in V[G]$ (in fact $p\in V$) such that for all integers $n\geq 2$ and all $\Sigma_n$ formulas $\varphi$, there is a $\Sigma_n$ formula $\varphi'$ such that for all $x\in V[G]$, we have
$$x\in V\wedge V\models\varphi(x)\iff V[G]\models\varphi(p,x).$$
This is because the relation "$w=V_\alpha^V$" (in variables $w,\alpha$) is $\Sigma_2^{V[G]}(\{p\})$, and hence in fact $\Delta_2^{V[G]}(\{p\})$ (by taking the right $p$; see the proof of definability of $V$). But then standard considerations give the claimed reduction for $n=2$, and then one can use this and induction to handle $n>2$.

For $n=1$, it becomes a little less clear how to interpret the question, since we don't know that the ground $V$ is even $\Sigma_1^{V[G]}(V[G])$. If it is so definable, then the $\Sigma_1$-over-$V$ is clearly $\Sigma_1^{V[G]}(V[G])$. But here is an example (from large cardinals) where this fails:

Assume ZFC + there is a proper class of measurable cardinals. Let $\mathbb{P}\in V$ be some non-trivial forcing, and let $G$ be $(V,\mathbb{P})$-generic. Then there is no $p\in V[G]$ such that $V$ is  $\Sigma_1^{V[G]}(\{p\})$.

For suppose otherwise and fix $p\in V[G]$ and a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$
such that for all $x\in V[G]$, we have
$$x\in V\iff V[G]\models\varphi(p,x).$$
Let $\eta$ be a limit ordinal and $A\subseteq\eta$  with $A\in V[G]\backslash V$.
Let  $\left<\kappa_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\eta}$ enumerate  the first $\eta$ measurables $\kappa$ of $V$ such that $\mathrm{rank}(p),\eta,\mathrm{rank}(\mathbb{P})<\kappa$, in increasing order.

Let $\xi=\sup_{\alpha<\eta}\kappa_\alpha$.
Since $V_\xi^V\in V$, we have $V[G]\models\varphi(p,V_\xi^V)$.

The $\kappa_\alpha$ are all measurable in $V[G]$. Fix a $U_\alpha\in V[G]$ such that $V[G]\models$"$U_\alpha$ is a $\kappa_\alpha$-complete non-principal ultrafilter on $\kappa_\alpha$".
Consider the iteration of $V[G]$
in which we use the images (under itermediate iteration maps) of those $U_\alpha$ for $\alpha\in A$ (and nothing else). (That is, if $\alpha_0=\min(A)$,
then we first use $U_{\alpha_0}$, and then if $\alpha_1=\min(A\backslash(\alpha_0+1))$,
then we next use $i_{01}(U_{\alpha_1})$,
where $i_{01}:V[G]\to\mathrm{Ult}(V[G],U_{\alpha_0})$
is the ultrapower map, and etc.) Let $j:V[G]\to M$
be the resulting iteration map. Then for all $\alpha<\eta$, we have $\alpha\notin A$ iff $j(\kappa_\alpha)=\kappa_\alpha$ iff $\kappa_\alpha$ is measurable in $M$ iff $\kappa_\alpha$ is measurable in $j(V)$ iff $\kappa_\alpha$ is measurable in $j(V_\xi^V)$.  (Because these are the first $\eta$ measurables of $V$ which are $>\eta$, and $\eta<\kappa_0$, note that $\xi<$ every  measurable limit of measurables of $V$ which is $>\eta$, so no ``new'' measurables appear in the interval $[\kappa_0,\xi)$, except for $j(\kappa_\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in A$.) But $V[G]\models\varphi(p,V_\xi^V)$,
so $M\models\varphi(j(p),j(V_\xi^V))$,
and $j(p)=p$ since $\mathrm{rank}(p)<\kappa_0$,
and also $M$ is wellfounded, so by $\Sigma_1$-upward-absoluteness, $V[G]\models\varphi(p,j(V_\xi^V))$, and it follows that $j(V_\xi^V)\in V$.
But then working in $V$, and by comparing the measurables of $V_\xi^V$ with those of $j(V_\xi^V)$,
we can recover $A$, so $A\in V$, a contradiction.

(This argument is based on a certain example described in Steel's *Fine structure and iteration trees*, combined with methods used in some articles analysing the interaction between large cardinals and $\Sigma_1$-(in parameters)-definability over $\mathcal{H}_{\kappa^+}$ (e.g. by L"ucke, Schlicht, Schindler, M"uller).)

Maybe there is a weaker interpretation of "$\Sigma_1^V$ is $\Sigma_1^{V[G]}(V[G])$" which might still hold. E.g. given a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$, is there a parameter $p\in V[G]$ and a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi'$ such that for all $x\in V$, we have $V\models\varphi(x)$ iff $V[G]\models\varphi'(p,x)$? (I.e., $\varphi'$ doesn't have to figure out whether $x\in V$ or not.)

A second question is whether we can avoid or reduce the large cardinal assumption above.

Comment: Thank you! That turned out to be refreshingly straightforward.